# Build a model with parameters combinations in fast way

Tags: r, loops, apply, lapply

I am trying to build ARIMA model in R with a set of parameters. The signature of `arima` function is:

```
arima(x,
      order=(p, d, q),
      seasonal=list(order=(P, D, Q), period=S)
)
```

I am experimenting with the parameters `p, q, P, Q` (assuming `d` and `D` are fixed to `1`).

Say each parameter is a vector:

```
p = c(1, 2, 3)
P = c(1, 2, 3)
q = c(2, 3, 4)
Q = c(2, 3, 4)
```

How could I build the ARIMA models with combinations of parameters? I know a nested loop is the intuitive way but I guess there is more R-style approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can place all your parameters into a data structure

```
params<-data.frame(p,P,q,Q,d=1,D=1,S=4)
```

Then you can use `lapply` over the rows and `with` to execute in the environment of each row.

```
lapply(1:nrow(params),function(i) with(params[i,],
  arima(x,order=c(p, d, q),seasonal=list(order=c(P, D, Q), period=S))))
```

If you mean all possible combinations of `p,P,q,Q` then set params to `expand.grid(p=p,P=P,q=q,Q=Q)` instead. But, see `auto.arima` from `forecast` for a stepwise approach.

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend looking into the `forecast` package, and in particular, the `auto.arima` function. It's really great. The author of the package even has a text book, which you can buy a copy of or [read online](https://www.otexts.org/fpp).

Also, I should add that you will run into trouble using @A. Webb approach – not that it's bad from a programming standpoint, but `arima` does a check to make sure that proposed models are statistically stationary. So you'll either have to `edit(arima)` to remove that line, or do the test ahead of time to make sure you don't suggest non-stationary parameter sets, or wrap the whole thing in a `tryCatch`. I've done all of these myself. The simplest approach is ultimately to make use of the hard work that has been put into `auto.arima`.

Comment: Thank you. I read the documentation. I did tried `auto.arima` but it seemed to not able to deal with irregular ts. If I feed a `zoo` to `auto.arima`, it is implicitly converted to a `ts` with `frequency=1`, then `auto.arima` would never include seasonal terms (P, D, Q).

Comment: You have to make a time series regular by padding the missing time steps with NA's. Regardless of what you're doing, you'd have to define the seasonal frequency anyway (i.e., this isn't something you only have to do for `auto.arima`). You don't need to use zoo. Just use `ts`, and define the frequency. I think the forecast package even has a function for this. Do `ls("package:forecast")` and look at the functions ... one of them is obviously named to indicate that it finds or detects the seasonal frequency. @Zelong